# How to efficiently switch between two different subjects without losing productivity?

Tags: productivity, learning, learning-management-system

One thing I have noticed as a student is that when I have to switch between two different tasks that I am supposed to be doing, say, for example, studying for two different subjects I am reading, I have this time in the middle where I cannot focus on either of the tasks. I cannot entirely take my mind off the earlier one, nor can I do anything productive while switching.

I had tried to keep working on a single task for a long time, but this doesn't work when there are multiple courses we are required to take, with most of them requiring equal attention.

Is there any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: Task switching is at least a 15 minute hit to productivity each time.

Comment: "this doesn't work when there are multiple courses we are required to take, with most of them requiring equal attention" But do they all require attention every day of the week? I think you were on the right track with your idea of blocking longer time frames per course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to take a clean break. Exercise, especially aerobic exercise, is good for this. But getting a cuppa in a cafe or lounge where you can, perhaps, have a general conversation can also work.

Not everyone needs this, of course, but if you find that you have non-productive moments, make them productive in other ways; socially, health, family, ...

I recommend aerobic activity since it gets the blood moving through the body, including the brain. But things that use the brain in different ways than study can also be effective.

And, note that a break is "efficient" if it brings you back to work with increased vigor. Actually "effective" is perhaps a better way to describe it. And it works even if you aren't switching between subjects, but just "stuck" in some way.

In addition, note that the brain continues to work at a subconscious level for most people. A break can actually be as effective as continuing to "push" the brain toward a goal.